# Bash script doesn't work properly in crontab but does work manually

Tags: bash, scripts, python, cron

## Research

Perhaps I'm using the incorrect vocabulary, but I can't seem to find a duplicate of my issue.  I am trying to execute two programs within my shell script and cron is clearly executing the first script, but not the second.

## Goal

I have two python scripts, `views.py` that runs as a web server and `housekeeping.py` that takes care of some cleanup and update checks that the web interface need not worry about.  Currently, these can be manually started using `sudo /home/ubuntu/start_server.sh` and all works perfectly.  I am using port 80, so I need to run as root.

## Bash Script

The full bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

/home/ubuntu/py3env/bin/python /home/ubuntu/flask_portal/views.py &
/home/ubuntu/py3env/bin/python /home/ubuntu/flask_portal/housekeeping.py &
```

My understanding is that the `&` will cause applications to run in the background.

When I execute manually, the shell script works perfectly.

## Crontab

To open crontab, I am using

```
sudo crontab -u root -e
```

As I said above, I am using port 80 so I need to run my script as root.

Within the crontab file, I have a single entry:

```
@reboot /home/ubuntu/start_server.sh
```

## Results

When I execute by hand, both scripts start perfectly.  When I allow the server to restart and run the `start_server.sh` script itself, the web server `views.py` works just fine, but `housekeeping.py` never starts (I'm doing logging within that file, so it isn't generating the proper files).  In addition, when I execute `python aux | grep python`, I see that both `views.py` and `housekeeping.py` are executing.

Comment: If you're in a venv, don't you need to activate it? In all probability, the script is relying on some aspect of the environment that's available in a terminal and not when run by cron.

Comment: I haven't needed to activate a virtual environment before, so long as I specify the path of the venv as the program to execute.

Comment: In that case, try `sudo env -i /home/ubuntu/py3env/bin/python /home/ubuntu/flask_portal/housekeeping.py`

Comment: @muru I see that you wrote `sudo` in that line, but I can verify that the command is executing properly when I type in `sudo ./start_server.sh`.  Is there something there that I should put in the crontab or in the shell script?

Comment: Looks like it is running the `housekeeping.py` file with no issues.

Comment: Hmm. Where does the script save logs?

Comment: `/home/ubuntu/web.log`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49406/discussion-between-muru-and-slightlynybbled).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to muru, I was able to find the answer to my question.

As it happens, the bash script and the cron job are working correctly.  The `housekeeping.py` had an error that occurs when executed as 'root' and not 'ubuntu', but which I could not see.

The error was revealed by adding the following to the top of the bash script:

```
exec 2>/home/ubuntu/log
```

Which has the effect of piping the output of all programs started in the bash script into a log file.